CSRF token requirement if implemented JWT
Is CSRF token still required in code, if we have implemented JWT based authentication and authorization?

Required by who?

in spring boot application

CSRF is Cross-Site Request Forgery, which is an attack type, which forces authenticated users to execute something. For example, if you allow a GET request to be sent and do operations, like
https://your.site.com/delete-user/123

then, if this is allowed, someone may send you a link to this and if you open it, then the user will be removed on your behalf. So JWT will not protect you from JWT perse, you will need CSRF tokens to do so.
Don't forget that POST requests can be fabricated similarly, for example, if you embed a malicious Javascript file by accident that sends a POST request which is not to your liking, then the same kind of forgery could be possible.
So, in general it makes sense to have a CSRF token mechanism, a token generated each time a page is to be displayed, the token being expected on the next non-GET request and making sure that GET requests will not perform such changes as removing, editing content or so, but changing the acceptable request type for those to POST or something of the like.

but still if jsession id is provided using cookies....the attacker cant provide jwt..which results in 403?

@utkarshsharma we are not speaking of JWT attackers, but CSRF attackers. Let's suppose user X properly logged in to your app via JWT in some browser, where he has a proper session. If the app allows requests to be executed and perform write operations from a valid session without CSRF protection, then your user might send a request to perform such write operations and the server will not be able to determine whether the user actually intended to do it. So, if someone sends user X a link that is to be performing a request that user X is unaware of, it will nevertheless be executed in

@utkarshsharma the browser where user X has a valid session and, provided that there is no protection against such forgery, the request will be executed without X even knowing of it. In other words, let's suppose you logged in with JWT and your app allows write operations to be performed without CSRF tokens. If a GET or a a POST request is successfully triggered on behalf of the user who has already a valid session, then your JWT authentication will not protect you from such forgeries, so you will need a CSRF token to prevent that.

@utkarshsharma so 1. You log in via JWT, you have a valild session, 2. Someone successfully triggers a request on your behalf in your browser, where you are already authenticated 3. The malicious request will successfully be executed unless your app expects a valid CSRF token.

the browser where user X has a valid session and, provided that there is no protection against such forgery, the request will be executed without X even knowing of it. In other words, let's suppose you logged in with JWT and your app allows write operations to be performed without CSRF tokens.
If the API that performs write operation requires JWT in header. How it will allow to perform write operation without jwt token?

@utkarshsharma you will definitely need CSRF token. If you operate with some JWT being sent to the API and it is overriden each time you request the API, then your JWT is operating as a CSRF token too. So, please answer these questions: 1. Is all your sensitive operation sending a JWT to your API? If so, does it receive a new JWT from the API upon each such request? 3. Is your API also your IDP?

CSRF is an exploit used to trick users to submit a change request. JWT based authentication does not provided any protection for this, because the problem does not lie with authentication. Therefore, no authentication mechanism will protect you from CSRF.
Spring Security does provide some simple counter measures. Take a lot at their documentation for ideas.
